# Missing reputation level in FAQ on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, reputation

The reputation level for "create tag synonyms" of 2500 is missing on the FAQ page on StackOverflow. I do not see any edit button where I can edit or suggest an edit for this page, which I guess is kind of logical. 
It is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: I think it's by design that not everything is covered in the FAQ. For example, it's also missing "5 = participate in meta", "10 = remove new user restrictions", "75 = set bounties", etc. We want to keep things simple. We have a hard enough time getting people to read the FAQ.

Comment: hehe, ok. I understand. It seemed to me like a miss since nothing else in the 1000+ is missing after a quick comparison. If it is by design, this question can be closed.

Comment: I can't make that official call, just noting that it isn't the only thing excluded and guessing at an explanation.

Comment: Ok. I `flagged` my post so someone whom can make that call can make the decision to close this bug report or leave it open.

Comment: Well, that's sort of what this whole site is for. If I could have answered authoritatively, I would have posted an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional...only the fairly major milestones are covered in the FAQ list, to keep it readable.  The same applies not only to reputation section but the FAQ in general, it's not an exhaustive list of all things.

See it from this view...look at meta then consider how long the FAQ would be if it was all-encompassing :)